# Is it possible to get submap for unsorted map without loop?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I get instance of `Map` from another method

```
Map map = service.getMap();
```

Now I want to get arbitrary 10 elements from this map.

I know that I can iterate over the `Map.Entry` but I don't like this decision.

Is there another way?

Comment: you need 10 really random elements? stupid idea - you could extract all elements, shuffle it - select first 10. What's more important - why you need it?

Comment: Given that you cannot use random access on a map's keys the ovbious workaround would be to collect the keys in a `List`, `Collections.shuffle()` that `List` and take the 10 first elements...

Comment: @Mysterion random is not the aim. just any elements without duplication

Comment: what's the type of map you are using? is it hashmap/treemap etc?

Comment: Then you want to use the word "arbitrary".

Comment: sorry for bad English) fixed

Comment: @gstackoverflow, can you tell us what is your problem with  iterating over the `Map.Entry`?

Comment: @bpgergo I feel that it is simpe operation and I don't want to write a lot of rows of code with loop

Comment: @almas shaikh method cotract says that it is just Map without details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently what you want is 10 *arbitrary* elements from the map. This would be available with a simple Java 8 idiom:

```
set.entrySet().stream().limit(10).collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need only values, I would suggest approach like this:

```
Map map = service.getMap();
Object[] array= map.entrySet().toArray();
Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, 10);
```

or with generics

```
Map<Key, Value> map = service.getMap();
Map.Entry<Key, Value>[] array = (Map.Entry<Key, Value>[]) map.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[0]);
Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, 10);
```

The Map.Entry has `getKey()` and `getValue()`

Comment: @gstackoverflow the entrySet has the keys and values.

Comment: @Kate Welcome to StackOverflow, I took the liberty of adding generics so you can see that there is a key and a value.

Comment: Result of following code execution is a array of **Map.Entry<Key, Value>**

Comment: According my question result should be Map

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an intermediate List to hold the keys from which you then select random elements. For example, this code creates a Map of 15 elements and then selects 10 at random from it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
        map.put(x, "val: " + String.valueOf(x));
    }

    List<Integer> keyList = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    Map<Integer, String> randomMap = new HashMap();
    for(int x = 0; x < 10 && !keyList.isEmpty(); x++) {
        Integer key = keyList.remove(new Random().nextInt(keyList.size()));
        randomMap.put(key, map.get(key));
    }
    System.out.println(randomMap);
}
```

This also has the advantage that it's actually selecting random elements rather than the other solutions which just return the first 10 elements and would give you the same 10 each time.